# Не могу создать View с символом "точка" ASP.NET-MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mobile-web

Проблема простая. Хочу определить новую Index View для мобильных устройств Index.Mobile. По умолчанию студия норм генерит _Layout.Mobile с точкой. Но когда я создаю новую вьюху с точкой, то пишет следующее

[image: Ошибка]

В примерах по которым я учусь есть Index.Mobile. Почему я не могу ее создать и как это сделать? Думал дело в смени языков, но нет. На любом не хочет. Спасибо.

Comment: а это в какой студии?

Comment: В последней на вчерашние обновление

Comment: Похоже это [сломалось еще в 2013 студии](https://forums.asp.net/t/1998192.aspx?Can+no+longer+add+views+with+periods+in+the+name+Visual+Studio+Pro+2013+)

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решилась. Создаете ViewMobile а потом созданную переименовываете с точкой на "View.Mobile"